# Break a stick into $6$ parts - P(no piece is greater than $\frac13$)

Tags: probability, geometry

> **Problem:** We have a stick of length $1$ that we are cutting into $6$ parts with $5$ uniform and random cuts. What is the probability that no piece is greater than $\frac13$ in length?

The original problem asked was to find the probability that no piece is greater $\frac12$. That seems quite simpler than my follow up for $\frac13$, because for that,

P(no piece is greater than $\frac12$) = $1$ - P(at least one piece is greater than $\frac12$) = $1$ - P(exactly one piece is greater than $\frac12$) = $1 - 6 \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^5 = 1 - \frac{6}{32} = \frac{13}{16}$.

This is not true for the case of $\frac13$, as there can be more than one piece being greater than $\frac13$. I'm not sure how to proceed with it, any hints or approaches would help a lot!

Comment: $(1/2)^5$ assumes each part length is chosen uniformly from $[0,1],$ which is not what the question states. The cut points are uniform. So if you pick cut points $1/6,2/6,3/6,4/6,5/6,$ all cut lengths are $1/6.$

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved using the inclusion-exclusion principle. Lets do it in some detail.

You pick random numbers $U_1,\ldots,U_5$ uniformly on the unit interval. These cut the unit interval into 6 segments of lengths $L_1,\ldots,L_6$: ie $L_1=U_{(1)}$, $L_2=U_{(2)}-U_{(1)}$, etc where $U_{(i)}$ are the values in increasing order.

The probability $\Pr[L_1>1/3]$ is simply the likelihood that none of the $U_i$ are less than $1/3$. This probability is the same for all $L_i$, so
$$
\Pr[L_i>1/3] = (1-1/3)^5.
$$

There are 6 different $L_i$, so the probabilities for each of these would add up to $6\cdot(1-1/3)^5$. However, this has the problem that if two different segments are both longer than $1/3$, that case is counted twice: this is where the inclusion-exclusion principle comes in.

The probability that both $L_1>1/3$ and $L_6>1/3$ is the same as the probability that all $U_i\in(1/3,2/3)$: ie $\Pr[L_1,L_6>1/3]=(1-2/3)^5$. This probability is the same for all pairs of $L_i$, so
$$
\Pr[L_i,L_j>1/3] = (1-2/3)^5\quad\text{for all $i<j$}.
$$
We can pick pairs $i<j$ in 15 different ways.

In principle we should have to proceed to handle cases where three or more of the segments are larger than $1/3$, but since that is not possible in this case we can stop.

The probability that no segment is longer than $1/3$ now becomes
$$
\begin{split}
\Pr[L_i\le1/3\text{ for all }i]
&= 1 - \sum_i \Pr[L_i>1/3] + \sum_{i<j} \Pr[L_i,L_j>1/3]\\
&= 1 - 6\cdot(1-1/3)^5 + 15\cdot(1-2/3)^5 = 66/3^5.
\end{split}
$$